# Android- Providing input to gridview from two different source

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I am trying to design a custom gallery for android. I am able to display images, but something is going wrong with Videos. I am new to Android, any help would be appreciated :)

The issue is I have two data source one for Images and other for Videos, so how to merge both the data and display together.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int count;
private int vcount;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private String[] arrPath;
private Bitmap[] vthumbnails;
private String[] varrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //sets UI of main page from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //get images from SD card and sort 
    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
    Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,null, orderBy + " DESC");

    //this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }

    final String[] parameters = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA};
    //final String vOrderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
    Cursor videocursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,parameters, null, null, null);

    int video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
    this.vcount = videocursor.getCount();
    this.vthumbnails = new Bitmap[this.vcount];
    this.varrPath = new String[this.vcount];

    for (int j = 0; j < this.vcount; j++) {
        videocursor.moveToPosition(j);
        int id = videocursor.getInt(video_column_index);
        int vDataColumnIndex = videocursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        vthumbnails[j] = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        varrPath[j]= videocursor.getString(vDataColumnIndex);
    }


    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    //imagecursor.close();
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.imageview.setId(position);

        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Lastscreen.class);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]), "image/*");
                intent.putExtra("path", arrPath[id]);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
        });
    holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
    return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
}
```

}

Comment: I am trying out similar thing. Do you have any same project for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to show only images in the Grid view.
2. Corresponding videos should stored in SD card
3. Image file names and video file names
4. First get the image names in arraylist and get the video names another arraylist, then compare it and get the data.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. So am i doing something wrong in the code i provided?? I have two different arrays and assigning image data to first and video data to other one. BUT ONLY IMAGES ARE SHOWN

Comment: Ok, how you want to show the videos, 
 User have to click the image and its re-direct to other Activity then the video will show.

(or)

When user click the image , then & there video should to run.

Comment: First way. User clicks the video and its redirected to other Activity

Comment: Well, In other activity how did you show the video using VideoView class ?

Comment: That I have not implemented yet, actually as I mentioned I am new to android, so have no idea how to do that also, but hopefully will figure out. So my main task is to display Videos and Images from the gallery(SD) in my custom gallery page, so for that I am using code mentioned above. For Image: when user clicks on Image its redirected to another activity and I am using ImageView to display it.

Comment: The best we can take it in offline, if possible you can give your gmail id for getting more info. Since you're new to android. :)